# Retorno de recurso persistido com Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

Boa tarde. Gostaria de entender como resolver a seguinte questão:

No projeto que estou atuando, o Backend e Frontend estão apartados. Para persistir os dados estou utilizando o Hibernate e para controlar a conexão com o BD possuo um filtro que abre a conexão no inicio da request e encerra a mesma ao retornar a response.

O caso de uso é: No frontend o utilizador cria um usuário novo relacionando a um perfil.  Já existem dois perfis cadastrados no BD sendo:

```
1 - BASICO
2 - ADMINISTRADOR
```

Usuário e Perfil são representados por classes diferentes:

**Classe Usuario:**

```
@Entity
public class Usuario{
   @Id
   private Long id;
   private String nome;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="id_perfil")
  private Perfil perfil;
}
```

**Classe Perfil:**

```
@Entity
public class Perfil{
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private String nome;
}
```

**Exemplo da classe UsuarioController:**

```
public class UsuarioController{

  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Usuario> salva(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {

     usuarioDao.salva(usuario);

     return new ResponseEntity<Usuario>(usuario, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
```

**Exemplo da classe UsuarioDao - método para salvar:**

```
public void salva(Usuario usuario) {
            // estou utilizando esta estratégia para gerenciar a conexão no BD
    EntityManager manager = JpaUtil.getEntityManager();

    manager.persist(usuario);
}
```

**O JSON recebido do Frontend para cadastrar usuário é:**

```
{
    "nome":"usuario novo",
    "perfil":{
        "id":1
    }
}
```

**O JSON retornado do Backend para o Frontend é:**

```
{
    "nome":"usuario novo",
    "perfil":{
        "id":1
        "nome":null
    }
}
```

Após o utilizador concluir a criação do usuário novo na tela, a aplicação direciona ele para a tela Lista Usuários. Porém, no frontend ao incluir a nova linha contendo os dados do novo usuário na lista, a coluna perfil aparecerá o valor: null - compatível com o que está sendo retornado no JSON.

**Qual é a boa prática para este caso???**

Backend retornar também o nome do perfil no JSON, ou seja, antes de retornar o Usuario na response, fazer o seguinte na classe controller: ?

*alteração no retorno do UsuarioController - método para criar novo usuário*

public class UsuarioController{

```
  @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Usuario> salva(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {

     Usuario usuario = usuarioDao.salva(usuario);

     Perfil perfil = perfilDao.perfil(usuario.getPertil().getId());

     usuario.setPerfil(perfil);

     return new ResponseEntity<Usuario>(usuario, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }
}
```

O Frontend deveria fazer uma nova request passando o ID do usuário criado, para que receba o objeto completo?

Comment: Não entendi bem a dúvida ou problema. Você está tentando entender por que o nome do perfil está nulo no json retornado?

Comment: Olá Dherik. Já existem dois perfis cadastrados no BD sendo:  1 - BASICO,     2 - ADMINISTRADOR. Desde modo, ao criar um usuário, não é preciso "criar um perfil" porque ele já existe no BD. Ao criar um novo usuário, é feito apenas um relacionamento.  Com isso minha dúvida ficou mais clara? Por favor, releia a sessão a partir de "Qual é a boa prática para este caso???" - Obrigado.

Comment: Usar os relacionamentos seguindo [HATEOAS](https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS) seria a boa boa prática. No seu salvar vocês não precisa consultar o perfil, por padrão toda `*ToOne` é `EAGER`, então basta dar um `refresh`.O `persist` deveria já retornar o estado atual da entidade gerenciada, então tente retornar o usuário em `salva` e não `void` - como o Spring Data faz, por exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi você quer salvar o usuário passando o id de um novo perfil, é isso mesmo?
Se for isso, o valor do nome sempre será null.
@OneToOne por default é EAGER([documentacao OneToOne](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html)), então não adianta você carregar novamente, pois ele sempre será carregado quando a entidade usuário for carregada.
Vou lhe oferecer algumas sugestões de melhoria conforme pediu:

Sugestões de melhoria:

1) Sugestão: Arrumar o nome do método

```
     Perfil perfil = perfilDao.perfil(usuario.getPertil().getId()); //O que quer dizer perfil ??
     //Coloque alguma coisa mais clara, por exemplo
     Perfil perfil = perfilDao.recuperPerfil(usuario.getPertil().getId());
```

Método significa uma ação, então o ideal seria alterar o infinitivo, ficando em lugar de salvar.

```
 @PostMapping
  public ResponseEntity<Usuario> **salvar**(@RequestBody Usuario usuario) {...
```

2) Sugestão: Se é um relacional 1 para 1, então sempre haverá um usuário e um perfil, correto? 
Não seria melhor utilizar @Embedded, até porque suas entidades são pequenas?
Segue documentação: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-component

3) Sugestão: Se será sempre 1 para 1, o ID TALVEZ seja o mesmo, então utilize @MapsId 
Segue documentação: 
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html

**4) Sugestão: Pensando de forma orientada a objetos, acredito que um usuário possui um perfil, mas um perfil pode estar atrelado a vários usuários.
Por exemplo: A Maria(1) tem o perfil de Admistrador(1),
O Joao(2) também tem o perfil de Administrador(1).
Se for seguir essa forma iria mudar bastante o seu projeto, você iria cadastrar primeiro o Perfil e depois o usuário, e seria um relacioanmento @ManyToOne, que tambem é EAGER por default, e provavelmente solucionaria seu problema de null.**

5) Ultima sugestão: Caso você salve o usuário e o perfil juntos e o mapeamento esteja correto, então passe o seguinte no JSON:

```
{
    "nome":"usuario novo",
    "perfil":{
        "id":1,
        "nome": "Administrador"
    }
}
```

Dessa maneira provavelmente resolverá o null que está retornando.

Sugiro realizar as sugestões de numero 1,2 e 4.

Comment: Olá Thiago. Obrigado por todas as sugestões. Sobre seu item 5, você chegou perto de responder minha dúvida e de fato, ao ler seus comentários vi que acabei não comentando que os perfils já estão cadastrados no BD. Isto ocorre no Startup da Aplicação, sendo: 1 - BASICO, 2 - ADMINISTRADOR. Desde modo, ao criar um usuário, não é preciso "criar um perfil" porque ele já existe no BD. Ao criar um novo usuário, é feito apenas um relacionamento.

Comment: Por isso o JSON enviado pelo Frontend é informado apenas o ID do Perfil e não o nome. E ai, surge minha dúvida: A request do Front, solicita a criação do usuário e a response do Back, por padrão, volta o JSON que eu especifiquei na descrição do tópico.

Comment: Suas tabelas estão sendo geradas pelo Hibernate??
Tente alterar o mapeamento para ficar
 @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="usuario", optional = true)
 private Perfil perfil;

E na entidade de perfil coloque:

@OneToOne
 private Usuario usuario;